# How to exclude one value and make everything that has that value NOT to be in calculation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

One `Policy Number` can have multiple different `ClassCode` and only one Total amount of `Premium`. In my SSRS report, I want to be able to create parameter `ClassCode`, and if I exclude (uncheck) at least one of those `ClassCode`, the whole Policy Number with Premium need to be NOT in a calculation.
Lets say, If I want to exclude `ClassCode 58`, then the `Premium` of 1,644.00 should NOT be in the result of my report.

[image]

I tried to say in my Query `AND ClassCode <> 58`, but it just excludes a one row and keeps the Premium anount. But my goal is to exclude everything if it has ClassCode 58.

```
SELECT policynumber,
       classcode,
       /*
       Using ROW_NUMBER() to check if it's the first record in the join and returns the Premium value if so, otherwise it will display 0. 
       The ORDER BY (SELECT 0) is there just because I don't need the row number to be based on any explicit order.
       */
       CASE
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (
                  PARTITION BY cte1.policynumber
                  ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) = 1 THEN premium
         ELSE 0
       END        AS Premium,
       c.yearnum  TransEffYearNum,
       c.monthnum TransEffMonthNum
FROM   cte1
       INNER JOIN cte2
               ON cte1.policynumber = cte2.policynumber
       RIGHT JOIN tblcalendar c
               ON c.yearnum = Year(cte1.policyeffectivedate)
                  AND c.monthnum = Month(cte1.policyeffectivedate)
WHERE  c.yearnum = 2016
       AND classcode <> 58
```

Comment: What table does ClassCode belong to?

Comment: ClassCode belongs to `cte2` in my query. I only show final `SELECT` statement here. Cause pretty long query.

Comment: So, for the example of your question, you want to eliminate Policy 3 altogether or you just want to Premium of ClassCode 57 to become 0?

Comment: I want to eliminate Premium of `1,644.00` , if I eliminate ClassCode 58. So yes, I want to eliminate the whole numbers associated with `Policy 3`

Answer (score 0):

you should first exclude all **Policy Numbers** that have the ClassCode that you want to set.
so instead of
`where       c.YearNum = 2016 AND ClassCode <> 58`

use

```
where  PolicyNumber NOT IN
(SELECT  PolicyNumber 
 From cte1 inner join cte2 on cte1.PolicyNumber=cte2.PolicyNumber
 WHERE ClassCode = 58);
```

and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate all the rows of Policy 3, this would probably works.

```
SELECT policynumber,
       classcode,
       /*
       Using ROW_NUMBER() to check if it's the first record in the join and returns the Premium value if so, otherwise it will display 0. 
       The ORDER BY (SELECT 0) is there just because I don't need the row number to be based on any explicit order.
       */
       CASE
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (
                  PARTITION BY cte1.policynumber
                  ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) = 1 THEN premium
         ELSE 0
       END        AS Premium,
       c.yearnum  TransEffYearNum,
       c.monthnum TransEffMonthNum
FROM   cte1
       INNER JOIN cte2
               ON cte1.policynumber = cte2.policynumber
       RIGHT JOIN tblcalendar c
               ON c.yearnum = Year(cte1.policyeffectivedate)
                  AND c.monthnum = Month(cte1.policyeffectivedate)
WHERE  c.yearnum = 2016
       AND cte2.policynumber NOT IN (SELECT policynumber FROM cte2 WHERE ClassCode = 58 and policynumber IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like right logic, but my query spinning forever. For some reason.

Comment: I guess your cte? are probably huge. But that is another issue. You might want to get rid of the policynumber=3 inside cte2.